# Unable to make Remote Connection with Postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, remote-access, remote-server

I have PostgreSQL running on Ubuntu Server and I want to make remote connection with PostgreSQL running on port 5432.

I've checked if I can ping the public IP of ubuntu server from my machine and that works fine.

Next I've changed two files on ubuntu server first I've changed `postgresql.conf` which looks as below

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'      # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                            # comma-separated list of addresses;
                            # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                            # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                 # (change requires restart)
```

Next I've added two lines in `pg_hba.conf` as below

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       trust
host    all             all              ::/0                            trust
```

Finally I checked if firewall is running by running `sudo ufw verbose` which outputted `inactive`.

As per my understanding I've allowed PostgreSQL to accept remote connection and firewall is also not present hence nothing is blocking. Still I get the following error.

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

How can I fix this error?

**Edit**

Although I can ping and ssh to the Ubuntu server using public IP but can not telnet.

I checked if port 5432 is open using this [link](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) but it turned out to be closed.

Comment: Did you restart the postgres service after you changed the config files? `systemctl restart postgresql.service` Also, I hope that's just a local test DB.

Comment: yes I did restart

Comment: If two version of postgres have been installed on that machine, one might be running on port 5433. Can you ensure that a postgres service is running on 5432? I used this but you can find out other ways. `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep -E 'postgres.*LISTEN.*' | less`. If you see that all of the config is correct and it's running there. The problem must be elsewhere. Maybe a bad connection string or a gateway is rejecting the connection along the way.

Comment: It returns 2 rows both running on 5432 one for IPv4 and other for IPv6.

Comment: Can you connect to 5432 from the host Postgres runs on?  What error does the  remote client give when it fails to connect with Postgres?  By the way, Ping is not the ultimate proof of connectivity.  It uses a lower level transport layer than Postgres (ICMP vs TCP/UDP).  To verify connectivity from a remote client, I'd start up a simple http server (Node and Python both have easy to use http servers), then try to connect to it from a remote client.

Comment: Yes, I can connect to 5432 from host postgres runs on. The error is pasted in question and I am using Python to make remote connection.

Comment: You need to disable or poke a hole in *every* firewall between the two machines.  Checking just the end machine itself is not enough.

Comment: How can I check the number of firewalls present between two machines?